# Magento2 | Use category attributes for searching (Elasticsuite)

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, autocomplete

On my Magento2 site, I installed the elasticsuite plugin that leverages the elasticsearch search engine.
I have seen that elasticsuite uses attributes such as "name", "url_path", "description" to return category results when a customer types in a word.

My question is: How can I decide which attributes elasticsuite should take to filter the category search in the search bar?
Which file should I edit?

Thanks for any help!